# Verify my proof on $\gcd(n+2,2)\mid n, n\in \mathbb{N^*}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

$\gcd(n+2,2)=\gcd(n+2-2,2)=\gcd(n,2)$.

Now here's what i did..

- If $n$ is even then $2\mid n$ and $\gcd(n,2)=2$, so the statement is proven.
- If $n$ is odd then $\gcd(n,2)=1$, therefore $1\mid n$. Again it holds true.

Am i right? Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: That method works, but you need to verify the *equality*, i.e. that both the RHS *and* LHS gcds have the same value in both cases. But you only explicitly mention the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fine. Alternatively, by definition, $\gcd(n,2) \mid n$.